# MIPS Single Cycle - Why are MemRead and MemToReg separate?

Tags: mips

I'm currently studying the ins and outs of the MIPS single cycle processor datapath.

I can't find a reason, why there is a difference between MemRead and MemtoReg. My current understanding is that we set MemRead to 1 if we want to load something from data memory and if we load something we want to use it in a register, and if we don't want to load something we want to use the result from the ALU in a register (provided that RegWrite is set to 1). So why are there different signals for MemRead and MemtoReg?

Here is the datapath I'm using:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/ntSvcd3.png]

Comment: You must realize that not everybody has your textbook on its knees. Single cycle Mips is interesting for didactic, but it has never been build, and nobody knows its structure, except with your textbook. So how can we answer questions about some internal signals of its schematic? Maybe if you can join the schematic, it can be easier.

Comment: Oh sorry my bad, I thought I added a picture, here it is https://i.imgur.com/ntSvcd3.png

Comment: I think you are right. Both signals should be set at the same time, when doing some kind of ld.  Not sure why signals have been separated, but I think they will turn this arch to a pipeline one. In that case, signals will apply at different stages and must be different.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I think it's partly due to the fact that the memory needs to get its own control signal.

One important thing to keep in mind is that all multiplexor inputs are computed and then the correct output is chosen. Because of this, for an instruction that doesn't involve reading from memory, the ALU result still gets passed to the memory even if the MemToReg control signal tells the multiplexor to ignore the value coming from memory. So that means, without MemRead, the memory might think it's getting an address that's invalid and that could cause some problems. For example, the (not really address) "address" could be out of bounds or not word-aligned, which could trip a hardware exception.

Here's a diagram from the book [*Computer Organization and Design MIPS Edition*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0124077269) by Patterson and Hennessy – where if you read the caption, it might help answer your question:

[image: Figure 4.8 from Computer Organization and Design (MIPS) 5th Edition by Patterson and Hennessy]

*But*... why do MemRead and MemToReg need to be separate and not just one value that gets split and sent to both places? That, I'm not sure.

One possible reason might be that they're making a distinction between control signals that can get a "don't-care" value. In a case where MemToReg can get a "don't-care" value, MemRead might still need to get a 0 so that it won't cause any errors for the previously stated reasons.

Comment: But wouldn't  an "address out of bounds" throw a software exception, managed by the OS, and not a hardware one?

Comment: @A Poor I mean, I can't access a memory address that doesn't exist (e.g. if I have 64-bit address for a 32-bit memory, the 32 MSB will be discarded) but I can access an address that I'm not allowed to. But isn't this out of bouds exception managed by the OS and not the hardware?